# How does Linux decide the /proc/PID/stat "name" of a process?

Tags: linux, proc

Currently my machine has 5 processes running scripts through `python`, but Linux thinks only 2 of them have the **name** `python` (according to /proc/$pid/stat).  That is, `pgrep -af python` shows:

```
1784 /usr/bin/python -Es /usr/sbin/foo
2306 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/bar
16964 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/terminator --geometry=1400x1000
24137 python /home/me/bin/baz.py --arg 70000
25760 python2 -m guake.main
```

whereas `pgrep -a python` shows only:

```
24137 python /home/me/bin/baz.py --arg 70000
25760 python2 -m guake.main
```

Here are the **name**s that Linux has given to these processes:

```
% for pid in $(pgrep -f python); do cut -d' ' -f2 /proc/$pid/stat; done
(foo)
(bar)
(/usr/bin/termin)
(python)
(python2)
```

So how does Linux decide whether `python` or the script name will be the process **name**?  And why do `foo` and `bar` become the **name** when the `terminator` process gets the full path instead?

I assume the manner of invocation matters.  I don't know how these three programs were invoked, but here are their shebangs:

```
/usr/sbin/foo: #!/usr/bin/python -Es
/usr/bin/bar: #!/usr/bin/python
/usr/bin/terminator: #!/usr/bin/python
```

This one was definitely invoked using the shebang:

```
/home/me/bin/baz.py: #!/usr/bin/env python
```

And Guake is launched from a Bash script like so:

```
exec /usr/bin/env python2 -m guake.main "$@" </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

My naive guess is that `/usr/bin/env` causes the word following it to become the process **name**, but I assume there's more to it than just that.  (And even if that is the case, *how* does it assign that **name**?)

Answer (score 3):

This is down to a Linux:

When a program starts another, it should use the name of the executable file as command line parameter $0, but it may choose to do otherwise. The `Name` field of `/proc/PID/status` is always set to the name of the executable by the kernel (but truncated to 15 characters).

The application itself can change a name. You can get the longer name from `/proc/PID/cmdline` (read up to the first null byte).

Comment: So why does python sometimes show up as `python` and other times as the script name?  And why does the script name sometimes show up as just the basename and other times as the full path?

Comment: Application itself can change name: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33912448/3479860