# How to get the full executable name of a running process in Linux

Tags: process, filenames, proc

I'm writing a script which will use the filename of running processes. However, I'm unable to determine the **full** executable name of some processes.

Initially, I decided to query the `Name` entry in `/proc/PID/status` (or the second field in `/proc/PID/stat`). However, according to the [manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html), that field is always truncated to 15 characters, but I need the full name to avoid conflict/confusion.

An answer of [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/279782/how-does-linux-decide-the-proc-pid-stat-name-of-a-process) suggests to use `/proc/PID/cmdline`, but there are problems too. Some programs (e.g. chromium, electron) do stupid/smart things to the value in `/proc/PID/cmdline` so I can't just split the data there by `NULL` and directly get the program name as suggested in the manpage - they fill in a lot of things to the original argv[0] field and separate them by space, and I don't think merely splitting by space is a good choice because the path/filename may contain spaces.

This is even more complicated when I find out that some scripts (e.g. python scripts) are in the form `/usr/bin/python /path/to/script` while some are in the form `/path/to/script`. Though this is much easier to deal with as long as I have that field (without jams as above) and manually check and split.

Any ideas how to get the full program name/filename?
It doesn't matter if the name contains the full path or not because that can be easily dealt with (as far as I can see now).

Comment: What about looking up the target of /proc/PID/exe ?

Comment: @user60039 For general cases, there is a problem with symlinks. (See my comment to ilkkachu's answer.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`/proc/$PID/exe` seems to be what you're looking for:  ([`proc(5)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)

> **/proc/[pid]/exe**
>                 Under Linux 2.2 and later, this file is a symbolic link
>                 containing the actual pathname of the executed command.  This
>                 symbolic link can be dereferenced normally; attempting to open
>                 it will open the executable.

So, simply:

```
$ /bin/cat & readlink /proc/$!/exe
/bin/cat
```

It actually follows renames on the executable file:

```
/tmp$ cp /bin/cat . ; ./cat & mv cat dog ; readlink /proc/$!/exe
/tmp/dog
```

Comment: For most cases it works well, but there is a problem with symlinks (if I identify the problem correctly). If the original command is a symlink to another file, then `/proc/[pid]/exe` would dereference the symlink and point to the actual file. Though for my case this behaviour won't harm.

Comment: @renyuneyun, hmm, yes, for the same reason my example of moving the executable after starting it works like it does, the `exe` entry tracks the actual file. `cmdline` would have the name the program received as `argv[0]` on startup, but IIRC that can be overwritten... I'm not sure but it comes to mind that to get a copy of the `argv` as it was when the process exec'd, you'd need to trace it.

Comment: Yes, `cmdline` can be overwritten. This is the reason I didn't want to use it in the first place (but sadly I still need to use it when `exe` points to the interpretor, e.g. python). What do you mean by "you'd need to trace it"? In the original program (or by modifying kernel)?

Comment: @renyuneyun, trace as in with a debugger to peek into the `argv` values before they're changed, or run under `strace` to see the `exec` syscall.

Comment: Aha, it doesn't seem to fit my needs. But anyway, I learned something new :)

Answer (score -1):

On a platform with a standard `procfs` with procfs-2 support, you get the result via:

```
ls -l /proc/<pid>/path/a.out
```

The file a.out is a symlink to the absolute path of the binary.

Note that the question did not mention Linux and for this reason, it makes sense to give information on how this feature works on the `procfs` original implementation from the procfs inventor Roger Faulkner.

Comment: Well, actually, the question title explicitly mentions Linux. But you're right in that it's not tagged or mentioned in the text.

Comment: Correct, there is no linux tag and even if there was one, my answer could help others to understand how it works on other platforms. If you look at various GNU programs, you will see that information on `/procfs` is widely missing and software that claims to be portable is frequently not when it tries to use `/procfs`.